# Adjusting a RegEx to require 2 digits after an optional decimal?

Tags: regex

I believe I've found the "perfect" Regular Expression to check against for currency in jQuery Validate, except it seems to allow the user to put a single lone decimal at the end or a decimal with a single digit after.

Matches: 700. and 3.0

The Regex:

```
^\$?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|0(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$
```

I've been playing with it in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but can't seem to modify it in the right places to fix my decimal issue.

Currently it matches everything I need it to:

700,000
700,000.00
700000

Here is the jQuery validator addMethod using @Kolink's regex for those of you curious:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("currency", function(value, element) {
     return this.optional(element) || /^\$?(?=.)(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,?\d{3})*)?(?:\.\d{2})?$/.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid number.");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In each case your regex is saying "blah blah blah, then optionally a decimal point followed by zero to two digits".

Try this instead:

```
^\$?(?=.)(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,?\d{3})*)?(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

It's a much simpler regex and it does everything your current one does... but better.

Breaking it down:

- `^` start of string
- `\$?` optional dollar sign
- `(?=.)` require at least one character (because your requirement is for the whole part to be optional, and the decimal to be optional, but requires at least one)
- `(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,?\d{3}))*)?` optionally match an integer. This integer may or may not be thousand-separated. Must start with a non-zero digit.
- `(?:\.\d{2})?` optionally match a dot followed by two digits.
- `$` end of string

Comment: Relatively, you're right; but there's a good few times I look at regular expressions and they *still* look like the darkest of witchcraft. They are definitely not, yet, 'simple' (to me, at least). =/

Comment: @DavidThomas I hear that. They are a black magic XD It's all computer language to me, I tell it what to do and it does it.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks for the breakdown! I updated the main post with my jQuery validator addMethod() and included your regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
^\$?(?=.)([1-9]\d{0,2}((,\d{3})*|\d*))?(0?\.\d\d)?$
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/FWHvPq2RBj) of this working with your examples.

Comment: Missing the optional dollar sign at the start, and doesn't allow `.99` or similar. Also doesn't allow `1000.00`, it requires `1,000.00`

Comment: @Kolink you're good :) what about now? everything optional, but look ahead to assert *something+

Comment: Now you've just stolen my answer, except you still haven't made it allow the absence of thousand separators XD

Comment: @Kolink stolen? I didn't even know you had given an answer (I'm using an iPhone and the visible area is kinda small). I could say the same of you, couldn't I. Never the less, I think I've fixed it and added a demo link. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, that seems... whoa, still wrong. Your regex now allows `1,2340.56` - note the four digits after the thousand separator.

Comment: @kolink It doesn't match 1,2340.56 (and never did). see (new) link.